# driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)") does not scoll down till the end of the page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.ungm.org/Public/Notice")
driver.maximize_window() #maximize the window size
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

> https://www.ungm.org/Public/Notice this page updates its table data using javascript. I want to **scrape** it but first I need to load all the table which loads dynamically. although the above program scrolls down but it is not scroll till the end of the page.

[image]

> I want all 771 items should be displayed but it scrolls down as much as I can see only 30 items.

Comment: it would be great if anyone could help me with the code.  I am trying to learn how to scrap webs and how to use selenium. your help would have a great impact on my learning process.

Comment: Not scrap, __scrape__

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to scroll *indefinitely* until scrolling is no longer possible (no more loaded content):

```
def scroll(driver, timeout):
    scroll_pause_time = timeout

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            # If heights are the same it will exit the function
            break
        last_height = new_height
```

Using `scroll(driver, 2)` would scroll, wait for 2 seconds then check If the scroll height has changed (new content), If not then it probably reached the end which will result in a break out of the loop.

**Note:** Adjust the timeout argument (in seconds) depending on how long on average it takes to load the content.

Comment: thank you ! I don't know why but still it does not scroll till the end of the page. it scrolls one more time then mine one.